# ZF2 2.5 not always showing full error message

Tags: php, exception, zend-framework2, php-7, error-reporting

Since I updated Zend-Framework to version 2.5.3 and PHP to version 7.0, I don't always get the full error message if an exception occurs.

e.g.: an exception occured and the only way I can get the exception message is by using the debugger (Class: ExceptionStrategy, Row: 121):

[image]

In the frontend, only a generic error message is displayed:

[image]
I have turned on the PHP error reporting (in my local.php and php.ini):

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);
```

Oddly enough, sometimes I get the full error message including the stack-trace and everything I need for debugging, but sometimes I only get just that generic error message.

I would expect it to look like this:

[image]

Has someone experienced that behavior? Is that normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok now I found it. The problem was in my error template because there is an if-statement which checks if the exception is an instance of Exception:

```
<?php if(isset($this->exception) && $this->exception instanceof Exception): ?>
```

Since PHP 7 most errors are reported with error exception, so I had to extend the if-statement like this:

```
<?php if(isset($this->exception) && ($this->exception instanceof Exception || $this->exception instanceof Error)): ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is causing your problems but worth mentioning it anyway.

You have to configure your view-manager to display/render exceptions. You can read more on how to configure your view renderer inside the [ZF2 documentation here](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.view.quick-start.html#configuration).

There is a dedicated key inside the view manager config:

```
'display_exceptions' => true,
```

Comment: I have already set display_exceptions to true. Even if the exception occurs in the same action it sometimes gives me the full stack-trace and sometimes not